# R xyplot with log axis to show numbers in decimal format

Tags: r, numbers, format, scale, lattice

I have a plot that I draw using xyplot in library(lattice). I use the log base 2 scale for the y-axis.  The numbers on my access show up as 2^0, 2^2, 2^4.  How would I be able to use the same scale but show the numbers in normal format as 1, 4, 16, rather than the format above.  I looked up a few format commands but it did not work for me.  Here the xyplot command I use.

```
xyplot(Conc~hr_Nominal, data_6681, type="b", groups = location, 
   auto.key = list(corner = c(1, 0), x = 0.95, y = 0.8),
   scales = list(y = list(log = 2)))
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix it. By the way, it would be helpful if specifying the package in your OP `library(lattice)`. As I do not have your data, I cannot run it on my machine. Please let me know if it doesn't work.

```
xyplot(Conc ~ hr_Nominal, data_6681, type = "b", groups = location, 
   auto.key = list(corner = c(1, 0), x = 0.95, y = 0.8),
   scales = list(y = list(log = 2), equispaced.log = FALSE))
```

Comment: Yes, that did fix it. Thank you for the clear response.

Comment: I am glad it helps. Thanks for the question